# Constrain an element within container to create a javascript slider

Tags: javascript, dom, slider

I am trying to create a pure javascript version of a jquery slider control.

I am not sure if this is the correct approach to take but here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/tharmer/xU35P/65/

```
document.getElementById("my-bar").addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);

function mouseUp()
{
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function mouseDown(e){
 window.addEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function divMove(e){
  document.getElementById('my-bar').style.left = (e.clientX) + 'px';
  //document.getElementById('my-slider').style.overflow = absolute;
  //var coOrds = document.getElementById('my-coords').innerHTML=(offSetX);

}
```

Is it possible to constrain the dark grey bar within the lighter grey bar so it doesn't go over the edges ?

Is this a good way to approach this task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this isn't a bad idea. You just have to add an if statement to check the bounds and also subtract the bar's width from the calculation

```
function divMove(e){
    if(e.clientX < parent.offsetLeft + parent.clientWidth // Upper bounds
       && e.clientX >= parent.offsetLeft) // Lower bounds
        document.getElementById('my-bar').style.left = 
                                            (e.clientX - bar.clientWidth) + 'px';
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xU35P/67/)

It's generally good practice to save elements to variables for readability and reusability

On a side note, HTML5 introduced a new [`range` type](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.range.html) for `input`s that might interest you for modern browsers